# Will Windows Phone questions be on topic when Windows 10 is released?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, tablets

Will [Windows Phone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone) questions be on topic when [Windows 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10) is released?

Releated: [How are we going to deal with Windows 8 on ARM?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4885) and [Should Tablet Computer questions be allowed on Super User?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3266)

Windows 10 is going to run on all devices - TVs, PCs, Tablets, Mobiles, XBox, etc...

Because of that, will anything running the new OS be on topic (not just PCs)?

The answers to those questions suggest that the answer to this will be yes, although there was a lot of disagreement in the comments...

Comment: If Windows runs exactly on a phone as it does on a desktop then I'd be interested but I would probably preclude smartphone only topics such as installing a different "ROM" or things of that ilk.  If instead they are simply progressing the phone only Windows Phone OS then no, I would not consider it on-topic.  We already have [windowsphone.se].

Comment: [It is struggling](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone)... I think Window phone and the revived proposal Microsoft should be combined into this site.

Comment: We will address this problem when its a problem.  We don't even know what it will be called let alone when it will be released.

Comment: Okay, just wanted a general idea of yes or no :) Thanks.

Comment: @Mokubai Windows Phone is in public beta for nearly thousand days (over two and a half year) and has less then 10% of required new questions quota per day (having 1.4, where 15 is needed). I'm pretty sure, that their "struggle" could end soon with clousure and that is why I think, that whether questions about Windows Phone are on topic or whether this beta site should be combined into Super User, should be disucussed _now_. It seems to be the problem right now.